# border radius is zero when use after psoudo element

Tags: html, css, class, validation

i user bootstrap form , i want to insert `*` after any input (in invalid input with red color and in valid input with green color)
i have to use `<span>` tag after any input to show `*`
but when i use `<span>` and `::after` pseudo element input border radius  is `0` but i  want to no change border radius .

```
input:invalid+span::after {
  content: "*";
  font-size: large;
  color: red;
}

input:valid+span::after {
  content: "*";
  font-size: large;
}




   <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
       <div class="input-group mb-2">
            <span class="input-group-text">
                <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
            </span>
            <input required type="number" class="form-control"><span></span>
       </div>
   </div>
```

MyCode:
[CodeLink](https://codepen.io/Hadi-Hi/pen/zYMNQBP)

Comment: modify you css to this      .input-group input:invalid+span::after {
  content: "*";
  font-size: large;
  color: red;
}

.input-group input:valid+span::after {
  content: "*";
  font-size: large;
  color: green;
}

Comment: This code is applied: `.input-group>:not(:first-child):not(.dropdown-menu):not(.valid-tooltip):not(.valid-feedback):not(.invalid-tooltip):not(.invalid-feedback) {
    margin-right: calc(var(--bs-border-width) * -1);
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}`

Comment: when use ```<span>``` tag border radius is 0 but i want to no change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by this styles it worked

```
input:invalid+span::after {
  content: "*";
  font-size: large;
  color: red;
}

input:valid+span::after {
  content: "*";
  font-size: large;
  color: green;
}


.input-group:not(.has-validation)>:not(:last-child):not(.dropdown-toggle):not(.dropdown-menu):not(.form-floating) {
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).